# Is linear regression suitable for discrete numeric dependent variable when responses are bunched?

Tags: r, regression

I am conducting regression analysis and my dependent variable is derived from dividing the number of candidates standing in an election by the number of vacancies. This gives me a discrete dependent numeric variable, which is throwing up issues in the diagnosis of my linear regression model.

Are there alternative types of regression I could use - or is it generally fine to use linear regression?

| cand/vac | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1098 |
| 1.3333333 | 159 |
| 1.5 | 659 |
| 1.6666667 | 316 |
| 2 | 7552 |
| 2.3333333 | 952 |
| 2.5 | 1933 |
| 2.6666667 | 902 |
| 3 | 14244 |
| 3.25 | 3 |
| 3.3333333 | 1291 |
| 3.5 | 1416 |
| 3.6666667 | 847 |
| 4 | 15528 |
| 4.3333333 | 458 |
| 4.5 | 445 |
| 4.6666667 | 222 |
| 5 | 7777 |
| 5.3333333 | 31 |
| 5.5 | 51 |
| 5.6666667 | 11 |
| 6 | 2048 |
| 6.3333333 | 2 |
| 6.5 | 3 |
| 7 | 336 |
| 7.5 | 1 |
| 8 | 35 |
| 9 | 3 |

Comment: What is the relationship between `cand` and `vac`? Why does the ratio result in these particular values? Can you give us some context and maybe also show the data for these two.

Comment: @user2974951 this is based of electoral data in the UK, where typically each ward has either 1, 2, or 3 vacancies. 'cand' is the number of candidates put up for election, and since cand is divided by either 1, 2, or 3, the dependent variable always ends in .0, .5, .33333 or .66666.

Comment: I see, is there a reason you are modeling the ratio instead of the number of candidates directly and using vacancies as an explanatory variable in the model? The number of candidates is a count variable and you could use Poisson regression as a result.

Comment: @user2974951 the logic behind the ratio is that we would expect there to be more candidates when there are more vacancies in a ward, but I will try a Poisson regression and control for the number of vacancies